# In sql-server according to syntax, who has to go first: DECLARE or SET NOCOUNT ON?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In sql-server according to syntax, who has to go first: DECLARE or SET NOCOUNT ON?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `declare` statement will not generate a rowcount message so there is no observable difference between the two.